# Is it possible to use html/css to adjust margin of select/option dropbox

Tags: html, css

I am using a select/option element on a web page. When I click on the select, the options appear to cover the text of the next paragraph.

```
 <tr>
      <td valign="middle" colspan="2">
        <select name="park_cars">
          <option value="">-</option>
          <option value="<50">&lt;50</option>
          <option value="50-100">50-100</option>
          <option value=">100">&gt;100</option>
          <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
        </select>
     </td>
</tr>
<p>some text...</p>
```

I would like to be able to adjust the margin so once you click on the dropdown, it pushes the paragraph down until you make a selection.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: **1. This isn't a question. 2.** There is no CSS-only method of reliably *reliably* determining if a select list is "open" - `:focus` is close, but can trigger in instances where the list is still closed. Furthermore you'd need to reconfigure your HTML - your `select` is nested *deeper* than the element you'd like to modify, therefore you won't be able to target it with CSS (remember, the C stands for *Cascading*!). Your options as it stands are Javascript, or restructuring your HTML and using `select:focus`, which again, isn't always indicative that the menu is open.

Comment: The `<select>` dropdown is (1) OS-dependent and (2) not part of the document layout flow, so you can't set calculate the height of it, nor access it using JS. Also, pushing texts underneath a dropdown **defeats the original purpose of a dropdown element**, don't you think?

Answer (score -1):

No. It isn't possible using select/option.

(Since the answer is no, my following solution will be conceptual, while you don't have any other code.)

However you can use another type of selection like check boxes if it accepts multiple values or radio buttons otherwise.

Place those elements inside a `display: none;` div and when you click somewhere you change css to `display: block;`. Then it will work like you want.